# Are query strings in golang safe?

Tags: go, query-string

Consider the following fetch of the URLParam userId passed on a URL:

```
userId := http.Request.URL.Query().Get("userId")
```

Is this safe (escaped and ready to be used in a db call) as it is or do I need to escape it /sanitize it before use?

Comment: Nothing should ever be assumed "safely escaped" - always use your database driver's parameterisation.

Comment: Thanks. Redis hasn't got such a method afaik but thanks anyways.

Comment: You didn't mention Redis—which isn't vulnerable because it's a key:value store. Values aren't inspected/processed, and commands are separate from data (unlike SQL).

Comment: Redis was an example of a "database" that has no such method. The fact that values aren't inspected there is irrelevant. The use of that value may later be in such context that it became harmful. Never mind, it's not important. I got the answer below and accepted it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not db-safe, and you should use the database driver's escaping before putting anything in it.

You should use functions like `sql.DB.Query()` that let you pass arguments and properly escape them. http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query

e.g.

```
userId := http.Request.URL.Query().Get("userId")

rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?", userId)
```

Comment: what if userId == "1' or 1=1 -- -'INSERT INTO users ...'

Comment: @dalu it gets escaped in a way that wouldn't cause problems.